# Using "ifelse" and/or "unite" to combine data from 3 variables into one in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I am aiming to combine information currently presented in three variables into one variable to create a "tidy" dataset.

The data frame has three variables indicating the diet type of a species: Carnivore, Herbivore, and Omnivore. The data is presented as "YES" or "NA", where "YES" is used to indicate the diet type and "NA" for the two types that the species is not. I am hoping to create a new variable "diet type" that is either numeric (0, 1, 2) in nature or is a character vector "Carnivore", "Herbivore", "Omnivore" using `ifelse` function, but continue to get errors when I try to run the code.

animal_diversity_raw %>%
mutate(animal_diversity_raw, diet= ifelse(Carnivore== "YES" & Herbivore== "NA", "1"),
ifelse(Carnivore== "NA" & Herbivore== "YES", "2"),
ifelse(Carnivore== "YES" & Omnivore== "NA", "3"))

The error is:
Error in ifelse(animal_diversity_raw$Carnivore == "YES" & animal_diversity_raw$Herbivore ==  :
argument "no" is missing, with no default

Appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the nested `ifelse` closing bracket should be at the end

```
animal_diversity_raw %>%
  mutate(diet= ifelse(Carnivore== "YES" & Herbivore== "NA", "1", 
               ifelse(Carnivore== "NA" & Herbivore== "YES", "2", 
               ifelse(Carnivore== "YES" & Omnivore== "NA", "3"))))
```

NOTE: Here, we assume the missing values as a string `"NA"`.  Usually, it would be unquoted and that can be checked with `is.na`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have changed the code to read: animal_diversity_new <- mutate(animal_diversity_raw, diet = ifelse(Carnivore== "YES", "1",
+    ifelse(Herbivore== "YES", "2",
+ ifelse(Omnivore== "YES", "3")))) ... I am successfully getting the new diet variable created and "1" for those that are Carnivores. However, the Herbivore and Omnivore observations remain as NA for the new variable.. Any thoughts?

Comment: @sehoskins As I mentioned in the post.   if you have `NA` without quotes, you need `is.na`  If you can show a small reproducible example in your post by editing (preferably with `dput(head(animal_diviersity_raw))`, I can get the structure